# NDEF message to switch Wi-Fi on/off

Tags: java, android, nfc, ndef

We're creating a simple android app for reading and writing to `NFC` tags, focused mostly on the `NDEF` technology. We're able to write an `NDEF` message with an `NDEF` record containing a URI.

However, we also need to write such message that turns the `NFC` tag into a Wi-Fi switch - reading it would cause Wi-Fi to turn on/off.

What kind of data do we need to write to the `NDEF` record to achieve this? Is it some sort of binary data, or a special "syatem" URI that android recognizes and takes appropriate action?

Comment: NFC/NDEF itself can't do that. You'll need a receiving app which does this for you; and in that case, you can define the message type and format yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but why not post it as an answer? I would accept it :)

Comment: It's not much of an answer, but it might help someone in the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFC/NDEF itself can't do that. You'll need a receiving app which does this for you; and in that case, you can define the message type and format yourself.